# Android gallery problem setting image size via xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

In the gallery tutorial they create a new ImageView in code and apply *Gallery.LayoutParams*.
I use a gallery with a custom adapter and want to inflate a imageview from xml and use that as the gallery item. **The problem is, that the given size (see item xml definition underneath) is disregarded.**

Custom Adapter:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
     final ViewGroup parent) {

  ViewHolder holder;
  if(convertView == null) {
     convertView = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.coverflow_item, null);
     holder = new ViewHolder();
     holder.coverImage = (ImageView)convertView;
     convertView.setTag(holder);
  } else {
     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }

  m_imageCache.download(m_imageUrls.get(position), holder.coverImage);
  return convertView;
}
```

Item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="120dp"
     android:layout_height="120dp"
     android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
```

Is there a way to apply the Gallery.LayoutParams in the xml?

PS: I know that i could apply the Gallery.LayoutParams in code, but this is only a simplefied case ... the gallery item in my case is a bit more complex and that is the reason why i want to do it in the xml.

Comment: pls comment if my question seems unclear to you (or if it's utterly stupid) ...